# How to implement Priors for KNN in matlab

Tags: matlab, bayesian, knn

I have a question concerning KNN training. I want to implement the KNN like in the book [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) by C. M. Bishop. We need to find the conditional density, *p(x|C_k)=K_k\N_kV*, the uncondidtional density *p(x)=K\NV* and the class priors, *p(C_k)=N_k\N*. Then, substitution into Bayes theorem results in the posterior probabilities.

My problem lies in programming. Lets assume I have 5 classes, in those classes my feature vectors are of different length. So class 1 has `100`, class 2 has `344`, class 3 has `541` ... class 5 has `n`. And all of them add up to the full dimensionality of 100 (number feature vectors) and a label vector of number of FV 1.

Now my questions: When I want to implement my priors now I can't just iterate with a `for loop` over all classes, because all my classes (different length) are stored in one matrix with feature vectors one after another

```
%% Code fragment out of ML-KNN: A lazy learning approach to multilabel learning Min-Ling Zhang, Zhi-Hua Zhou
for i=nclass
   temp_Ci=sum(train_target(i,:)==ones(1,num_training));
   Prior(i,1)=(Smooth+temp_Ci)/(Smooth*2+num_training);
   PriorN(i,1)=1-Prior(i,1);
end
```

So, how can I implement the priors in Matlab?

Comment: Are you saying that for each example the number of features depends on its class?

Comment: No, say it that way. I do have a full feature set of 12000 instances with each 64 features (Spectrogram data). Those 12000 instancees are subdivided into 5 classes. My problem now is that the number of feature vectors for each class are of inconsitant number. I know I cant use the above code example, but how would i implement it for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: So, you are saying that the data set has different number of examples per class (a.k.a. imbalanced data)?  (ref: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~qyj/IR-Lab/ImbalancedSummary.html)